# To draw an image on the surface of the another image (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, drawing

world! I have a question for you. Just how can I only with jQuery draw an image on the surface of another image? Is it real? If you know some docs about the subject please type a link. I want a source code that can run on IE6 and older. Thanks to you!

Comment: What do you mean by "draw an image"? You mean you have two existing images and you want to place one on top of the other, or do you mean that you want to draw image from scratch, pixel by pixel?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use jQuery to draw anything.

You could something like http://raphaeljs.com/ but it won't work with pre IE6 browsers.

Comment: You can use it to track the path of the mouse as in my example ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into something like this, depending on how much interaction you need:

http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad